# How to cast alternate sign on controller?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I'm playing The Witcher 3 on PC through Steam Big Picture Mode using a Nintendo Switch Pro Controller (not that I think the controller's type matters anyway).

During play, I invested a point into the alternate version of the sign Axii, and as soon as I did it, a mini tutorial on how to cast it showed up. Something like "hold some button, then press this another button".

I skipped it really fast accidentally, and I cant find the info anywhere in-game. I have searched all the button schemes, controller bindings, options, tutorials ... everyting.

So, please: how do I cast an alternate sign? what are the commands for doing so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hold down the right trigger to activate the sign. Make sure you have it equipped or it will just cast the regular version.

Comment: I tried it and was able to cast the alternate form of sign IGNI, but still no success while trying alternate AXII. Is there any difference between them?

Comment: Alternate Axii makes opponents fight for you temporarily. It has to be used while looking towards an opponent. Geralt will then stop moving, cast the sign with his hand, then "push" the glyph towards the opponent in his animation, at which point the opponent's head will start glowing (hold down the trigger the whole time). Alternate Igni acts like a sustained flamethrower for as long as you're casting it, draining stamina gradually.

Comment: Well, it seems to me that this is the correct way, even though it felt pretty unreliable for alternate AXII. I don't know if I am not focusing on an opponent correctly, or if was never able to go throught the entire animation.